# Nginx location exclude specific folder

Tags: nginx

i am trying to include all js|css in nginx location except specific directory

Currently i have this

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 7h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

I have js files in `/javascriptfoldertwo/` which i wan't to make it expires 2 hour.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ServerFault @leon.

While answer by @Tero should work, there is an alternate approach to it. This approach utilizes *nested locations* in Nginx. Here's the actual code...

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 7h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    location ~ /javascriptfoldertwo/ { expires 2h; }
}
```

You may know more about how `location` works at https://nginx.org/r/location. Please search for the text "nested" to know more in it and limitations in using a nested `location` block.

The obvious advantage with this method is that... you don't have to be consious about the order of executiion. For example, the following works too...

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    location ~ /javascriptfoldertwo/ { expires 2h; }

    expires 7h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx uses the first matchin regex location that matches the condition. Therefore you can have the following setup:

```
location ~* ^/javascriptfoldertwo/ {
    expires 2h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(?:js|css)$ {
    expires 7h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```